# "expected primary function before "int" c++

Tags: c++

I'm new on programming and I need to learn it for Arduido purposes. I used this code to test some things but I keep getting the "expected primary function before "int"" error, and it also says that the position functions isn't declared.

Am I declaring it wrong? I've tried many different things and kept getting the same message. My objective is to keep typing '1' and get 3, 6, 9, etc on the screen from calling the position function at cout.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
 { 
 int degree=0;
 int r=1;
 while (r != '0')
  {
  cin >> r;

  // this is where I get the error //

  int position()
   {
    if ( r == 1 )
    { 
    degree=degree+3;
    }
    return degree;
   }
  cout << position();
  }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You can't nest functions in c++

Comment: You should probably read a basic C++ tutorial/book before you start to write your own programs.

Comment: Thank you!Could make it work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function `position` is in your function `main`, which is not possible in c++. Move the `position` out of the `main` function.

```
int position(int r, int degree)
{
  if ( r == 1 )
  { 
    degree=degree+3;
  }
  return degree;
}

int main()
{ 
  int degree=0;
  int r=1;
  while (r != '0')
  {
    cin >> r;
    cout << position(r, degree);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `r` and `degree` will be out of scope in position()

Comment: Pass them as parameter of the `position` function.

Answer (score 2):

Nesting functions is not allowed in C++. Change your code to be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
// code
}

int position()
{

}
```

Comment: `position()` must be declared before `main()`, if it is to be called from `main()`.